# polynomial time in?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, american-english, mathematics

Related to [exponential in terms of?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123509/exponential-in-terms-of) (nonetheless different from it):

Assume that you have an algorithm (producing gizmos) whose inputs are three numbers *t*, *d*, and *h*, which are interpreted by a human as the number of thingums, doodahs, and hickeys. Suppose the running time of the algorithm is the function *g*, which depends on *t*, *d*, and *h*. Further, let *g*(*t*,*d*,*h*) ≤ *dᶜ*, where *c* is some expression exceeding 1 and depending on *t* and *h*, but not on *d*.

I would like to use plain English to express this fact (e.g., in an abstract) in a simplified way. Do we write

> The algorithm runs in polynomial time in the number of doodahs.

or

> The algorithm runs in polynomial time with the number of doodahs.

?

My English teacher corrected it to

> The algorithm runs in polynomial time in terms of the number of doodahs.

I think this cannot be quite right.

Which version is correct? And how about

> The algorithm runs in worst-case polynomial time in/with the number of doodahs.

Any better version?

I welcome answers from mathematicians who are native AmE speakers and have an excellent command of English.

Comment: You might find a more targeted audience in http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I understand.  :)

Comment: @LeonMeier This is out of my expertise, so this is a genuine question, not an answer, but wouldn't polynomial time be if  `g(t,d,h) ≤ dᶜ` where c is a constant?  Your time function doesn't appear to be bounded by a polynomial with a constant  degree - since C is a function of other inputs to the algorithm.  Or is the function `c(t, h)` bounded by a constant above?

Comment: Got it.  In that case I would say it runs in polynomial time _with respect to_ the number of doodahs (and in exponential time with respect to the number of things and hoosiewhatsits).  That's a very common construction when describing mathematical functions:(Eg The value of a continuously compounded investment varies linearly with respect to present value and exponentially with respect to time.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, "polynomial time" is already jargon so you're out of the realm of "standard" English.  Unless there was a good reason not to, I would be explicit and use the actual math to describe exactly what the polynomial looks like and what factors into the equation.  Example from the Wikipedia article on [Time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Polynomial_time):

> The Euclidean algorithm for computing the greatest common divisor of two integers is one example. Given two integers a and b the running time of the algorithm is bounded by O((log a + log b)<sup>2</sup>) Turing machine steps. This is polynomial in the size of a binary representation of a and b as the size of such a representation is roughly log a + log b.

If it's not necessary to be explicit, you can just say "the algorithm runs in polynomial time".  Otherwise there is probably a lot of leeway in how you phrase it, since statements like this rely more on the math than English grammar.

> The algorithm runs in polynomial time (based on)/(relative to)/(varying with) the number of doodahs

Comment: I wouldn't have had a clue what ***polynomial time*** meant until a few months ago, but I hear it a lot since I've started watching Youtube talks by computer scientists and mathematicians. And so far as I can recall, it's never explicitly qualified by anything like ***with respect to** [something]* - the context is always one where they're talking about an algorithm that either solves or approximates some equation containing one or more ***exponential*** terms (where without that clever new approach the time required would be expected to rise exponentially with those variables).

Comment: @FumbleFingers the algorithm runs in polynomial time, but the polynomial itself is an equation that takes a certain number of variables.   I'm not sure how to summarize, in a word, the relationship between the equation and its variables.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an idiomatic contraction of "in the domain of the numbers of doodahs". The polynomial is a function in the domain. Otherwise the preposition doesn't make much sense and I'd prefer "to run over/through the numbers".

Comment: "The function runs in polynomial time in the domain of the number of Xs." I  might be wrong (but downvoters didn't comment why). Given that the function is a relation of the time t **over** the values X, I'd still tend to use over. but *in* is shorter so if you are writing, that might save some space at least.